# Lenovo Ideapad Z585 screen remains black on restart

Tags: windows-8, boot, reboot, lenovo-laptop

hope I'm posting this in the right place. Basically I've had my Lenovo ideapad z585 for a while, but recently it's started doing this thing where if the laptop is turned off/restarted, when it is powered back up again the lights of the buttons turn on but the screen just stays black. The only way I can find of getting the laptop to boot again is to wait for the battery to run out before turning it back on again. Hard resetting or removing the battery doesnt seem to solve the problem.
Has anyone else had this problem, or maybe know what might be causing it?

Comment: What happens if you remove the battery and push the power button, reinsert the battery and start up as normal? What about powering up only using the charger, with the battery out?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I've tried both of your suggestions but neither seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the "Power Management" software that Lenovo ships with, and this needs to be re-installed.

Now for the strange part: in order to fix this, you will need to hold a flashlight at the screen because the back-light will be completely turned off! I know this is kind of strange, but it genuinely is the only way you will be able to see the screen in order to complete the re-installation process.